# React Redux Mapping state to props not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I'm trying to learn React with Redux and so far I think I've been able to work out most of the code needed to make it work but I'm having an issue with getting my state passed down to my component. I am using Visual Studio 2017's ASP.NET Core project template that has react and redux  boilerplate codes and they used this:

```
export default connect(
  state => state.weatherForecasts,
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(FetchData);
```

I tried doing the same thing with my own component like so:

```
export default connect(
  state => state.lecture,
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(LectureTable);
```

but when trying to access the contents of my props, the properties I want to get are tagged as undefined. I checked through Redux devtools that my initial state exists but my component is unable to  see the props I'm trying to pass to it. The weird thing is I just imitated the boilerplate code but it isn't working yet the boilerplate code works just fine (ie I can go to the component and log out its initial state).

Since I'm following the format used by Visual Studio,my actioncreators, reducers, and constants are in one file shown below:

```
const GET_LECTURES = "GET_LECTURES";

const initialState = {
    lectures: [],
    selectedLecture: {},
    isLoading: false,
    test: 0
};

export const actionCreators = {
    requestLectures: isLoading => async (dispatch) => 
    {    
      if (!isLoading) {
        // Don't issue a duplicate request (we already have or are loading the requested data)
        return;
      }

      dispatch({ type: GET_LECTURES });

      const url = `api/lecture/`;
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const lectures = await response.json();

      dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_LECTURES, payload: lectures });
    } 
  };

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case GET_LECTURES:
        return { ...state, isLoading: true }; 
        default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

I'm sorry if its all messy. I'm really just starting to begin to understand redux..

**Edit**
My component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button, Table, Label, Menu, Icon} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {actionCreators} from './../../store/Lecture';

export class LectureTable extends Component {

  componentWillMount(){
   // this.props.requestLectures(this.props.isLoading);
    console.log(this.props.test);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Table size='large'>
        {/*removed to make it cleaner..currently only has static data too lol*/}
      </Table>
    )
  }
}



export default connect(
  state => state.lecture,
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(LectureTable);
```

where my store is configured:

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import * as Lecture from './Lecture';
import * as Counter from './Counter';
import * as WeatherForecasts from './WeatherForecasts';

export default function configureStore(history, initialState) {
  const reducers = {
    lecture: Lecture.reducer,
    counter: Counter.reducer,
    weatherForecasts: WeatherForecasts.reducer
  };

  const middleware = [
    thunk,
    routerMiddleware(history)
  ];

  // In development, use the browser's Redux dev tools extension if installed
  const enhancers = [];
  const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
  if (isDevelopment && typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.devToolsExtension) {
    enhancers.push(window.devToolsExtension());
  }

  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing: routerReducer
  });

  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
  );
}
```

my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import App from './pages/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

// Create browser history to use in the Redux store
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');
const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: baseUrl });

// Get the application-wide store instance, prepopulating with state from the server where available.
const initialState = window.initialReduxState;
const store = configureStore(history, initialState);

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement);

registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Can you post your component code?

Comment: @Davo just added it.

Comment: You're missing an 's': `state => state.lecture` should be `state => state.lectures`. You probably want to wrap the lectures array in an object { [prop]: state.lectures }` though or simply pass state.

Comment: @FK82 I don't think that was the cause... but I guess that was my fault...my redux state tree goes like: lecture -> lectures[], isLoading, test <---test is what I'm trying to get to log to know that I was able to get my props.

Comment: @kobowo Ok, well your initial state doesn't reflect that.

Comment: I'm guessing if you do `state => console.log(state)` it's an empty object? Are you actually making the store? I.E. importing your reducers, combining them with `combineReducers()` [if there are multiple], passing that to `createStore()`, and passing that to a wrapping `<Provider>` component? (I image there are alternate way of doing it but something in that process may be the issue).

Comment: @SamVK yes I am combining the reducers and passing the created store to a provider. It was all in the boilerplate code and I edited it to include my own code. That's why I'm so confused tbh... the boilerplate code works with the code shown above but when I try to do the same format with my own code I end up with undefined

Comment: Then share those parts please. Especially reducer combining part.

Comment: @devserkan added it.

Comment: It seems OK. But clearly, we are missing something here. Just follow the suggestion in @Olivier Boissé's answer's comments. Try to console.log the entire state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. First of all I'm a noob both to stackoverflow and to react so I apoligize for all my inconsistencies (if thats the right term?).

**What I found out:**

1. I am using react router
2. I was doing the connect method to a subcomponent of the component being rendered by the router
3. I placed the connect method to the parent component and it worked

**Some notes:**

- state => state.lecture still works
- I will take all of your advices to heart and change my code accordingly
- The only reason I was adamant with solving the problem using the code I had was because I couldn't accept the fact that boilerplate code wouldn't work unless I had done something specifically different from what the boilerplate did. I just didn't take into account that the router played a huge role with it.
- I repeat...I'm a react noob so I'm sorry for wasting your time T_T

**Edit again:**
I was able to connect a different child component with the Redux store. I'm trying to look at why I still can't do it for that specific component that caused me to ask this question. I'll update my answer once I find the reason.

Comment: No problem with that :) It is a good thing you've found the problem and shared the answer.  I've realized my mistake here. We all said, "You are doing it wrong, use the `connect` like this". But, as we can see it works like that but personally I don't like opening a state like this. `state => state.lecture` works but you will have props as  `this.props.test`. Without looking `connect` we can't understand where is this prop coming from. Also, when you want to add a second state property you should change the shape the one explained in the answers.

Comment: Yeah I&amp;#39;ve noted all your suggestions and will start trying to shape them to follow proper conventions. I just wanted to make sure the boilerplate I had was working haha. Thanks for the helps!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! If this fixed the problem you can mark your own answer as the accepted answer (to both close it and for others that may come by looking for the solution.)

Comment: @SamVK thanks for the info! I'll do it in two days then cuz apparently I can't right now lol

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to [connect()](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) should be a function that returns an object - with the props you want added as keys, and their value being the value from state. e.g.

```
state => ({ lecture: state.lecture })
```

Comment: Or `({ lecture }) => ({ lecture })` with destructuring and object property shorthand syntax.

Comment: I tried this... didn't change anything. My prop still shows up undefined.. I did try removing the part with bindActionCreators just to make sure that it wasn't causing it but yeah still wasn't passed

Answer (score 1):

I think in their example `weatherForecasts` is an object. In your example `lectures` seems to be an array so I suggest to rewrite your `mapStateToProps` function like this if you only need to get the `lectures` prop

```
state => ({ lectures: state.lectures})
```

if you need the whole `state` you can have `state => state` so you can access the props `this.props.test` and `this.props.lectures`

Keep in mind that `mapStateToProps` should return an `object`, not an `array`. By the way, in your reducer the field name is `lectures` (plural) not `lecture` so `state => state.lecture` will be `undefined`

Comment: I tried using this syntax and it works but I end up with undefined when I try to log this.props.test. I have a lecture object containing an array of lectures and a test prop that has an int value btw

Comment: @kobowo _@OlivierBoissé_ already told you why that happens: `state => ({ lectures: state.lectures})` passes a props object `{ lectures: state.lectures}` to the component. This does not have a `test` property and you will get undefined.

Comment: did you try with `state => state` or `state => ({test: state.test, lectures: state.lectures})` ?

Comment: @FK82 a lecture object (supposedly) is holding this similarly how to weatherForecasts is an object containing properties inside such as forecasts, isLoading etc. so the properties in initialState above is wrapped (supposedly) by lecture and that's why I'm using lecture. Also what i still don't get is how weatherForecasts (an object and not an array -- this was Microsoft's naming btw) works without any problems.

Comment: Just try @OlivierBoissé's advise. It is a good one. Just use it like `state => state` then log the props: `console.log( this.props )` Then we will look what you have there.

Comment: please read the doc https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options `mapStateToProps` should return an object so you can retrieve what you want from the `store` maybe just `lectures` or maybe `lectures` and `test` or maybe the whole `state`...

Comment: @kobowo Just log the entire state and see what you get: `export default connect(
  state => state,
  ...
)(LectureTable);` and then `console.log(this.props);` in `componentDidUpdate()`. No need to guess.

Comment: guys I found my answer...and I'm so ashamed I could really hate myself..

Answer (score 1):

Rick, your connect argument should be something like:

```
export default connect( state => {
    return {
      test: state.lecture // Or any value
    }
})(LectureTable);
```

You're trying to console log the `test` prop, so you should include it in your connect call.

Answer (score 0):

I think by doing the following steps, you can solve the issue:

1. First you need to call two functions when you want to connect your component to application state, one is mapDispatchToProps and another one is mapStateToProps, for your code to be clean, its better to define these functions separately and then pass them by name to connect, but if you want to use your own way you should do these changes: (assuming your reducer name is lecture from your combineReducers, and assuming you are calling requestLectures with this syntax: this.props.lectureActions.requestLectures() and importing lectureActions from the file you have written lecture related actions) :

   ```
   export default connect(
   state => state.lecture.lectures,
   dispatch => {lectureActions: bindActionCreators(lectureActions, dispatch)}
   )(LectureTable);
   ```
2. from above code, you do not need to export an object that contains the actions like actionCreators, you should export the requestLectures function out of it independently
3. add below case to your reducer so that when getting the lectures succeeds the state of the application gets updated with the lectures:

   ```
   case RECEIVE_LECTURES:
     return { ...state, isLoading: false, lectures: payload.lectures }; 
     default:
     return state;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here.

You are defining `mapStateToProps` function as the first argument to `connect` wrong. As many of answers explain this now you should use it like, this:

```
export default connect(
  state => ( { lecture: state.lecture } ),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(LectureTable);
```

Now, you have a `lecture` prop as your state. You can reach it with `this.props.lecture`. But in your `componentWillMount` method, you are trying to log it like `this.props.test`. It should be `this.props.lecture.test`.

By the way, try to use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` since it will be deprecated in the future releases.

Comment: I tried changing it to an object as shown by the previous answers and it works but when I change the props to this.props.lecture.test, I get an error saying this.props.lecture is undefined